# Getting "Error applying delegate" exception when applying GPU delegates on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, delegates, gpu, tflite

I am getting an error on applying GPU delegates on my Samsung Galaxy S22.
I have that checked that the GPU is present on the device.

I have to run inferencing on Android Mobile. I have updated all the build dependencies in the build gradle. I am following this link https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/android/delegates/gpu

I have updated the build dependencies and added hardware acceleration permission in the manifest file.

This is the error I am getting:

> Error: Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity: Java.long.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Error applying delegate

Code

```
Val tfliteModel = loadModelFile( applicationcontext, modelpath) 

Val options= Interpreter.options()
Var gpudelegate= Gpudelegate (). 

Val Options.addDelegate(gpudelegate)

Interpreter = Interpreter (tfliteModel , options) => code is breaking here
```

While using this code

```
val compatList = CompatibilityList() 
val options = 
Interpreter.Options().apply{ if(compatList.isDelegateSupportedOnThisDevice){
 // if the device has a supported 
GPU, add the GPU delegate 
val delegateOptions = 
compatList.bestOptionsForThisDevice 


this.addDelegate(GpuDelegate(delegateOptions)) }
 else { // if the GPU is not supported, run on 4 threads
 this.setNumThreads(4) }
```

---

`if(compatList.isDelegateSupportedOnThisDevice)=>` is giving false.